# file input to blob using canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image-processing, canvas

unable to insert blob to indexedDB please assint in inserting blob from file to indexedDB :)

*CODE*

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>file to BLOB</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      </head>
    <body>
      <div id="test">
        <input id="File" type="file" accept="image/*" capture="user">
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
<script src="js/idbConn.js"></script>
```

*Javascript*

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#File").change(function(){
      const File = this.files[0];
      const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
      const optBlob = cvs.toBlob(function(cvsBlob){
        let fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(File);
        let imgFile = new Image();
        let imgFile.src = fileURL;
        imgFile.onload = function(){
          cvs.width = imgFile.naturalWidth;
          cvs.height = imgFile.naturalHeight;
          let ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(imgFile,0,0);
          URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
        }
      },File.type,0.3);
      const data = new Object();
      data.blob = optBlob;
      let trx = db.transaction(["imgBlobs"],"readwrite").objectStore("imgBlobs").put(data,"test.jpeg");
      });
    });
</script>
```

trying to directly insert file into indexedDB but blob is as undefined

> if kept cvsBlob in data.blob blank image is storing in indexedDB

Comment: The File object you got at `this.files[0];` is already a Blob (File interface inherits from Blob), no need to draw your image on a canvas.

Comment: fot optimised blob i am going for canvas.toBlob()

Comment: "optimised blob"? A Blob is just a pointer to binary data in memory, no way it can be optimized or deoptimized. If you mean an optimized image file, then I really wonder what kind of optimization you are expecting. For file size, HTMLCanvas png compression is about the worse you can get on the market. If you ever receive jpeg images, you'll blow their sizes. For drawing perfs, since they'll anyway be decoded to raw bitmap, it won't even be faster to draw these...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### There are a few problems.

- [`HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) does not return anything. You get the blob in the callback function.
- JavaScript is blocking, queued tasks (like the `toBlob` callback) events (like `onload`) will not run until the current execution has returned. This means that the line
  `const data = new Object();` is run before the toBlob callback has been called.
- You are calling `toBlob` before you have created, loaded and drawn the image to the canvas.
- `let imgFile.src = fileURL;` This line will throw a syntax error??

### Fix

- First load the image.
- On image load create the canvas and draw the image on it.
- Revoke the image url.
- Convert the canvas to a blob.
- In the `toBlob` callback add the blob to the DB.

### Example

Call the function with the file you get from the file input. Eg  `$("#File").change(function() { saveImageToDB(this.files[0]) });`

```
function saveImageToDB(file) {
    const fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    const img = new Image();
    img.src = fileURL;
    img.addEventListener("load", () => {
        URL.revokeObjectURL(fileURL);
        const cvs = document.createElement("canvas");
        cvs.width = img.naturalWidth;
        cvs.height = img.naturalHeight;
        cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        cvs.toBlob(blob => {
            // Code to add blob to database. Put your db code in here
            db.transaction(["img"], "write").objectStore("imgs").put({blob}, file.name);
        }, File.type, 0.3);
    }, {once: true});
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much